# Best practices to keep a Cairngorm Flex Project DRY (don't repeat yourself)

Tags: apache-flex, coding-style, dry, cairngorm

I'm having a hard time building a Cairngorm Flex3 app that connects to a rails app...
I'm used to rails DRY approad, and the Convention over Configuration thing too.. and Cairngorm in awful at these.

How do you keep you flex code as DRY as possible?

I've implemented a generic delegate to avoid a delegate for each command, at least.
Any other idea?

Comment: Still possible to pick a different framework? Cairngorm is the least advanced of any of them. I'd recommend Mate or Glue (I'm the author of Glue).

Comment: God I'd love to.. I decided to learn cairngorm only because it had good documentation and tutorials.. You might still convince me to use Glue but the lack of docs and guides make me think I'll waste more time with trial and error than with the unDRY cairngorm repetitions..

Answer (score 0):

OK, well, here's what I did:

1. No use of Custom CairnGorm Events, simply make a common static dispatcher and dispatch Strings...
2. One common RESTful delegate
3. make components so that they inherit parent public vars (appModelLocator instance too!)
4. Create a generic ServiceUtil to send dynamic HTTPServices, no need for the SerivceLocator etc..

this is a nice improvement in my opinion!